# C# open a program in a form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open a exe in a form with below code.

This is open my program but outside the form.I want to have this program inside of my form.
Please Help
Regards

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Cadence Design Systems\Allegro Free Physical Viewers 16.6\tools\pcb\bin\allegro_free_viewer";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

Comment: what does "have this program inside of my form" mean?

Comment: Why does it need to open 'inside' your form?

Comment: Hi, I create form in C# then I want to execute the alegroo program but the program to be opened inside of my form.

Answer (score 2):

You can not run other application within your application using process, you can do it with [Object Linking and Embedding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) and the application you want to open from within your application should be complaint with `ole`. This codeproject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/467739/How-to-Insert-an-OLE-Object-Adobe-Acrobat-Document) explains how you can embed acrobat document within c# application.

Answer (score -1):

If what you're saying is that you want to have a window inside your Windows Form application, this isn't easily possible.

Your best bet would be to setup an MDI Host Window, and use the WinAPI `FindWindow` and `SetParent` to find the external process window (once started), and set the parent of this window to your own form host window.

Something like this (after importing the methods) should work:

```
Process p = new Process();

p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Cadence Design Systems\Allegro Free Physical Viewers 16.6\tools\pcb\bin\allegro_free_viewer.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "ProcessStart.cs";
p.Start();
var handle = FindWindow(null, "allegro_free_viewer.exe");
SetParent(handle, this.Handle);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Of course, the better way is to see if the application is able to provide an ActiveX / OLE control that you're able to embed into your application, rather than using an external process.

Comment: -1 for a solution that actually *would* allow him to embed an application in his own?